# How to do view Pdf spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf

Here I created API for view pdf part. 
This is my API url:http://localhost:8082/api/layout/samePdfview/20
Problems is when I call this API url first time,
and aslo show some error message

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/layout/pdf/20190215163504_editedLandscape_layoutPort.pdf] cannot be opened because it does not exist
"

It is working when stop the server and again run that pdf is display.
i could not find what is the problem ,anyone please help me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/diffPdfview/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET ,produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE} )

    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getDiffPdf(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<LayoutEntity> getdiffPdf = layoutRepo.findViewImages(id,1);//status=1
        String diffPdf = getdiffPdf.get(0).getdLayoutPath();
        String diffPdfStr = diffPdf;
        diffPdfStr = diffPdfStr.substring(diffPdfStr.lastIndexOf("/"));

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(new InputStreamResource(new ClassPathResource("static/layout/pdf"+diffPdfStr).getInputStream()));
    }
```

Comment: problem is you are not closing the input stream?

Comment: @AshokKumarN Hi  sir How to do that

Comment: are you generating pdf with this API or you use only for a view pdf

Comment: @AshokKumarN Yes ,I am getting pdf for this API,when i past this API url in Browser and enter ,That pdf is view

Comment: I cant see the pdf generating code in this api?

Comment: @AshokKumarN this it is not pdf generating code .it is read pdf and view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188474/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-n-and-gnanaseelan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this :**

```
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDiffPdf(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<LayoutEntity> getdiffPdf = layoutRepo.findViewImages(id,1);//status=1
    String diffPdf = getdiffPdf.get(0).getdLayoutPath();
    String diffPdfStr = diffPdf;
    diffPdfStr = diffPdfStr.substring(diffPdfStr.lastIndexOf("/"));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = diffPdfStr;
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename); 
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    Path pdfPath = Paths.get("static/layout/pdf"+diffPdfStr);            //"/path/to/file.pdf"
    byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdf, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
    }
```